# Why does lambda with expression = a function call require lambda arguments before the call?

Tags: python, function, lambda, expression

```
callbacks = []
my_dict = {'CodesAndValues': [('code1', 'value1'), ('code2', 'value2')]}

def my_callback(s: str):
    pass

def add_callbacks(cb_list: list):
    for code, value in my_dict['CodesAndValues']:
        cb_list.append((value, lambda c=code: my_callback(c))) # <--*********************

add_callbacks(callbacks)

for item in callbacks:
    val, fn = item
    fn(val)
```

The code provided may be overkill for my question, but it's what I used for testing. The code as shown works: a debugger shows that on arrival at my_callback the argument `s` has the expected value. But if I change the lambda to...

```
lambda: my_callback(code)
```

... it generates an exception: TypeError('() takes 0 positional arguments but 1 was given')
I'm not sure why. I have some vague, ignorant guesses related to binding of values. I'd welcome an explanation!

Comment: In your for-loop, where you iterate over `callbacks`, you call each lambda and pass in `val`. When you change your lambdas to `lambda: my_callback(code)`, the lambdas no longer take any parameters. The lambdas have a side effect of invoking another function with a single parameter, but that's not the same thing. The error is saying that you are trying to pass a value to a lambda that isn't expecting any parameters.

Comment: @PaulM. Thanks, that helps. After reading it I changed the last line to `fn()`; with that, the code runs to completion but on each of two arrivals at `my_callback` the argument `s` has value `value2`. I guess that's because that was the most recent binding for the lambda during `add_callbacks`.